# Combine multiple dictionaries by keys and values?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, combiners

After hours and suggestions from other posts, I could not solve my problem.
I have to manage many dictionaries (until now the only way I know to work).

For all four dictionaries that I want to combine, three of them have the same key (d1, d2 and d3).

```
d1 = {key1: [x1, x2, x3], key2: [y1, y2, y3], key3: [z1, z2, z3]}
d2 = {key1: [x4, x5, x6],key2: [y4, y5, y6], key3: [z4, z5, z6]}
d3 = {key1: [x7, x8, x9], key2: [y7, y8, y9], key3: [z7, z8, z9]}
d4 = {x2: [a, b, c], y2: [d, e, f], z2: [g, h, i]}
```

The fourth dictionary is a dictionary generated by a reference file containing metadata and their keys are equal to one value in `d1` and what I want is to create a dictionary with the informations from `d1, d2` and `d3` and after include the information of `d4` in the final dictionary.

```
final_dict = {key1: [x1, a, b, x2, x3, x4, x5, x8, x9],
              key2: [y1, d, e, y2, y3, y4, y5, y8, y9],
              key3: [z1, g, h, z2, z3, z4, z5, z8, z9]}
```

and print like this in tabular format:

```
key1  x1  a  b  x2  x3  x4  x5  x8  x9
key2  y1  d  e  y2  y3  y4  y5  y8  y9
key3  z1  g  h  z2  z3  z4  z5  z8  z9
```

At the moment I have a dirty script but "works".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("file1.txt", "r") as file1, open("file2.txt", "r") as file2, /
     open("file3.txt", "r") as file3, open("file4.txt", "r") as file4:

    d1 = {}
    d2 = {}
    d3 = {}
    d4 = {}
    dicts = [d1, d2, d3, d4]

    #d1 = {key1: [x1, x2, x3], key2: [y1, y2, y3], key3: [z1, z2, z3]}
    #d2 = {key1: [x4, x5, x6],key2: [y4, y5, y6], key3: [z4, z5, z6]}
    #d3 = {key1: [x7, x8, x9], key2: [y7, y8, y9], key3: [z7, z8, z9]}
    #d4 = {x2: [a, b, c], y2: [d, e, f], z2: [g, h, i]}

    for b in file1:
        row = b.strip().split('\t')
        if row[0] not in d1:
            d1[row[0]] = row[1], row[3], row[4]

    for c in file2:
        row = c.strip().split('\t')
        if row[0] not in d2:
            d2[row[0]] = row[1:]

    for f in file3:
        row = f.strip().split('\t')
        if row[0] not in d3:
            d3[row[0]] = row[1:]

    for m in file4:
        row = m.strip().split('\t')
        if row[0] not in d4:
            d4[row[0]] = row[1], row[3], row[2]

    final_dict = {}
    for k in (dicts):
        for key, value in k.iteritems():
            final_dict[key].append(value)

    print final_dic

    #key1  x1  a  b  x2  x3  x4  x5  x8  x9
    #key2  y1  d  e  y2  y3  y4  y5  y8  y9
    #key3  z1  g  h  z2  z3  z4  z5  z8  z9
```

The problem is the last 3 lines.

Because of the absent of deep knowledge, simple suggestions (for dummies) will be appreciated.

Comment: So, you basically want to merge dictionaries `d1`, `d2`, and `d3` on their keys? What happens to `x6`, `x7`, `y6`, `y7`, `z6`, and `z7`? I don't get the logic behind why they aren't included in your desired output.

Comment: I would recommend splitting out HOW you got the dictionaries into a different question. And just let this one focus on how to go from the many dictionaries into one.

Comment: In this case I don't want all information from *d3*. That's the reason they don't appear at the final output.
Thank you for the advice @Karnage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, although the logic as to why variables like `x6`, `x7`, `y6`, `y7`, etc. were excluded is yet unclear:

First, make these variables (e.g. `x1`, `x2`, etc.) exist, and assign their own name as string for their values for easier tracking of the results later:

```
values = [letter + str(number) for letter in 'xyz' for number in range(1, 10)] + ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
for v in values:
    exec('%s = "%s"' % (v, v))
```

Next, let's instantiate your dictionaries:

```
d1 = {key1: [x1, x2, x3], key2: [y1, y2, y3], key3: [z1, z2, z3]}  
d2 = {key1: [x4, x5, x6],key2: [y4, y5, y6], key3: [z4, z5, z6]}
d3 = {key1: [x7, x8, x9], key2: [y7, y8, y9], key3: [z7, z8, z9]}
d4 = {x2: [a, b, c], y2: [d, e, f], z2: [g, h, i]}
```

Then, let's merge the dictionaries into one, big, final `dict`:

```
new_dict = {}
for d in [d1, d2, d3]:
    for key in d:
        if key not in new_dict:
            # if key not yet in the dict, make it so
            new_dict[key] = d[key]
        else:
            # if key already there, then we'll just add the lists together
            new_dict[key] += d[key]
```

And, finally, to get the first two individual letters from `d4`, we can try this:

```
for key in new_dict:
    for other_key in d4:
        if other_key in new_dict[key]:
            new_dict[key] += d4[other_key][:2]
```

Check the output:

```
>>> new_dict
{'key2': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5', 'y6', 'y7', 'y8', 'y9', 'd', 'e'], 'key3': ['z1', 'z2', 'z3', 'z4', 'z5', 'z6', 'z7', 'z8', 'z9', 'g', 'h'], 'key1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'a', 'b']}
```

This is basically your desired result, except it includes the 6's and 7's. Can you provide some background as to why your desired output looks that way? Anyway, this should get you started.

Comment: Hi @not_a_robot. I defined the values for the strings in d4, including it just after the other defined values
    dicts = [d1, d2, d3, d4]
values = [letter + str(number) for letter in 'xyz' for number in range(1, 10)] + ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
    for v in values:
        exec('%s = "%s"' % (v, v))